# Artifactory default repository for missing jars

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

How do I specify a specific remote repository (i.e. search.maven.org) so that artifactory defaults to looking for missing jars from there? I have a box that has a strict firewall and I need to know the exact url in order to get access to these jars and currently it pulls from several different sources. I Want to force it to use only one or two so I can have the sys admins open up the domains.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [edit the remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories#RemoteRepositories-Offline) and set the ones you don't want to use to "Offline". Artifactory will not try to fetch artifacts from offline repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice you should create a [virtual repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) which will aggregate all the remote and local repositories you would like to resolve from.
The virtual repository hides the access details of the underlying repositories letting users work with a single, well-known URL. This way you can make sure that only remote repositories that you trust are being used. In addition the underlying participating repositories and their access rules may be changed without requiring any client-side changes.